# How to create this shape using css and html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, frontend

[image]

Hello! My team was hired to build a web app that can manage clinic records for a dentist, I am in charge of the front-end, how can I build the shapes that are shown on the image using web technologies (CSS, HTML, js)?

I didn't find any libraries that are built for this purpose.

Thank you!

Comment: Why not use actual image? Else it's 4 triangles and one block on top of them

Comment: SVG would be perfect here. Using CSS grids would also help.

Comment: "My team was hired", "I am in charge of the front-end", and the implied "i don't even know where to start" don't really go along well. If you have a specific problem with an attempt of yours, i bet people will help you.

Answer (score 1):

if it's to select a teeth, then a label input and a background could do.

basic idea to start from:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
  border: solid 1px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom left, transparent 0 calc(50% - 1px), black, transparent calc(50% + 1px)) no-repeat, linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent 0 calc(50% - 1px), black, transparent calc(50% + 1px)) no-repeat;
}

label input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox"></label>
```